# Setting the retry policy on a lambda function that has been rolled out using serverless

Tags: python, aws-lambda, serverless

I have a stack on AWS that I have deployed using serverless. I was about to write code to catch API exceptions *(from an external provider)* and then put them in another queue when I can across `SNS > Topics > Delivery retry policy` (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-message-delivery-retries.html) which is exactly what I want. The only problem is I can not find any documentation on how to describe it in my `serverless.yml`.

Can any give me an example of describing a sns topic retry policy in a `serverless.yml` file?

Answer (score 2):

You can do so in your function configuration in `serverless.yml`.

```
functions:
  asyncHello:
    handler: handler.asyncHello
    maximumEventAge: 7200
    maximumRetryAttempts: 1
```

Reference: https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions#maximum-event-age-and-maximum-retry-attempts